# SQLite pre-update hook re-entrant

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, callback

Im trying to use the new C interface of SQLite the preupdate hook:

https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/preupdate_count.html

Now to my question :
The pre_update API signature is the following :

```
void *sqlite3_preupdate_hook(
  sqlite3 *db,
  void(*xPreUpdate)(
    void *pCtx,                   /* Copy of third arg to preupdate_hook() */
    sqlite3 *db,                  /* Database handle */
    int op,                       /* SQLITE_UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT */
    char const *zDb,              /* Database name */
    char const *zName,            /* Table name */
    sqlite3_int64 iKey1,          /* Rowid of row about to be deleted/updated */
    sqlite3_int64 iKey2           /* New rowid value (for a rowid UPDATE) */
  ),
  void*
);
```

And as you see it injects to the callback a pointer to the db connection that registered the hook.
From my experience and from SQLite documentation I know that the update/commit/rollback hooks are NOT re-entrant which mean that they cannot modify the connection that cause to the hook invocation.

I want to use this pre_update callback to read and write from the database.

Now I got 2 questions:

1) Does the SQLite pre_update callback is re-entrant and got a support for modifying and reading the database from the callback's scope?

2) If it does, can anyone explain how the following is possible?

I created a new DB and run with SQLite shell the following :

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Parent(_index INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
sqlite> INSERT INTO "Parent" VALUES(1);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Child(_index INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, CONSTRAINT ch_fk FOREIGN KEY(_index) REFERENCES Parent(_index) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
sqlite> INSERT INTO "Child" VALUES(1);
```

Now i'm trying to create an automatic operation which should work inside transaction and update a child each time its father changes its key so it wont be a constraint violation.

NOTE: I know that i can achieve this behavior with triggers/SQLite foreign keys UPDATE mechanism but i'm willing to test the stability of this API.

so the code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int rc;
    char *err_msg;
    sqlite3 *sqlite_connection;

    rc = sqlite3_open("__database__.db",&sqlite_connection);
    rc += rc = sqlite3_exec(sqlite_connection, "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;", 0, 0, &err_msg);/* set foreign keys mechanism on */
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
        printf("Error initializing connection : %s\n",err_msg);
        exit(rc);
    }

    sqlite3_preupdate_hook(sqlite_connection,pre_hook,NULL);

    //Watch tables content before
    rc = sqlite3_exec(sqlite_connection, "SELECT * FROM PARENT;", callback, (void*)NULL, &err_msg);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(sqlite_connection, "SELECT * FROM CHILD;", callback, (void*)NULL, &err_msg);

    //BEGIN TRANSACTION
    rc = sqlite3_exec(sqlite_connection, "BEGIN", 0, 0, &err_msg);

    /* Update table to invoke callback */
    rc += sqlite3_exec(sqlite_connection, "UPDATE Parent SET _index = 2 WHERE _index = 1", 0, 0, &err_msg); /* Update table to invoke callback */

    //Watch tables content after
    rc = sqlite3_exec(sqlite_connection, "SELECT * FROM PARENT;", callback, (void*)NULL, &err_msg);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(sqlite_connection, "SELECT * FROM CHILD;", callback, (void*)NULL, &err_msg);

    rc += sqlite3_exec(sqlite_connection, "COMMIT;", 0, 0, &err_msg);

    if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
        printf("Error updating the database : %s\n",err_msg);
        rc = sqlite3_exec(sqlite_connection, "ROLLBACK", 0, 0, &err_msg);
        if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
            printf("Error updating the database : %s\n",err_msg);
        }
    }


    sqlite3_close(sqlite_connection);

    return rc;

}
```

And the pre_hook :

```
void pre_hook(
        void *pCtx,                   /* Copy of third arg to preupdate_hook() */
        sqlite3 *db,                  /* Database handle */
        int op,                       /* SQLITE_UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT */
        char const *zDb,              /* Database name */
        char const *zName,            /* Table name */
        sqlite3_int64 iKey1,          /* Rowid of row about to be deleted/updated */
        sqlite3_int64 iKey2){
             char query_buffer[100];
             char *err_msg;
             if((strcmp("Parent",zName) == 0) && (SQLITE_UPDATE == op)){
                 sprintf(query_buffer,"UPDATE Child SET _index = %d WHERE _index = %d",(int)iKey2,(int)iKey1);
                 if(sqlite3_exec(db,query_buffer , 0, 0, &err_msg) != SQLITE_OK){
                     printf("Error executin trigger\n");
                 }

             }
        }
```

Then i get the output :

//Before operation:
Parent :
_indx : 1

Child :
_indx : 1

//After operation:
Parent :
_indx : 2

Child :
_indx : 2
Error updating the database : FOREIGN KEY constraint violation

And as you see there is no violation at all!.

However when i change the main function as follows:

1)un-sign the pre_hook callback.

2)operate the Child update outside the callback (in our case right after the Parent update).

I suddenly get the same output just without the error.

I think this means that the pre_update callback is NOT re-entrant but I seek for professional answer for this questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html):

> The update hook implementation must not do anything that will modify
> the database connection that invoked the update hook. Any actions to
> modify the database connection must be deferred until after the
> completion of the sqlite3_step() call that triggered the update hook.
> Note that sqlite3_prepare_v2() and sqlite3_step() both modify their
> database connections for the meaning of "modify" in this paragraph.